# bookmarklet submitting an getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, bookmarklet

I am trying to make a bookmarklet to automatically add a value in the "jsActiveAmountInput" field and submitting this.
Adding the value works with this piece of code.

```
javascript:void(document.getElementById("jsActiveAmountInput").value = 20)
```

But I have no idea how to activate the span "jsActiveAmountButton" button for submitting.

```
<div class="place-amount-row" id="placeAmountRow">
<input id="jsActiveAmountInput" class="amount-input" type="number" pattern="\d*" placeholder="amount" data-lot-id="21311865">
<span id="jsActiveAmountButton" class="btn btn-orange" data-click="/amount/go" data-arguments="{lotId: 21311865, targetId: jsActiveAmountInput}">GO</span>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: post a working snippet

Comment: I love when spans are buttons, if only people actually used buttons. :) You can try to call the onclick() and see if that causes the event to fire.